# Java sublist not return a new instance of the list

Tags: java, sublist

I stumbled upon an issue where Java sublist does not return the instance of the list but returns the view of the list. Which resulted in to thread stuck.

I did some googling and found [this](http://teddziuba.com/2008/09/java-sublist-gotcha.html).

Comment: post your code or people won't believe you ;-p

Comment: This might have been clear when the link still worked, but now there's simply no question left here ...

Answer (score 8):

Yes, [`List.subList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) returns a view, as documented:

> Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive. (If fromIndex and toIndex are equal, the returned list is empty.) The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa. The returned list supports all of the optional list operations supported by this list.

And yes, creating a view on a view on a view ... can end up being a bad idea.

The moral of the story isn't "don't use `subList`" though - it's "make sure you know what the methods you're calling are supposed to do - read the documentation".

Answer (score 3):

Almost 8 years old thread! But still, I believe my answer might help someone.

As mentioned by Jon Skeet above, `subList` always returns the reference to the original List. 
A simple fix to this would be to assign it to a new ArrayList<>

For ex:

```
List<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();
x.add(1);
x.add(2);
x.add(3);
x.add(4);
x.add(5);
List<Integer> y = new ArrayList<Integer>(x.subList(0, 4));
```